# LiveData, MVVM and Repository Pattern

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

***Is this a good approach or I've just found a nasty workaround?***

I'm using `MediatorLiveData` class because seems useful to update the source of a `LiveData` object.

I mean, the majority of tutorials that I've found on internet just use `Livedata` or `MutableLivedata` without a dynamic source, in example:

```
fun search(/*no input params*/): Call<List<Person>>
```

But in my case, I have the following web service that performs a search by name:

```
interface APIServidor {
    @GET("search")
    fun search(@Query("name") name: String): Call<List<Person>>

}

public class PeopleRepository {


    public LiveData<List<Person>> search(String name){

        final MutableLiveData<List<Person>> apiResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Call<List<Person>> call = RetrofitService.Companion.getInstance().getApiServer().search(name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Person>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Person>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Person>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    apiResponse.postValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Person>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                apiResponse.postValue(null);
            }
        });

        return apiResponse;
    }
}
```

Then in the viewmodel class I'm adding source per new request.

```
public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MediatorLiveData<List<Person>> mApiResponse;
    private PeopleRepository mApiRepo;

    public SearchViewModel() {
        mApiResponse = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        mApiRepo = new PeopleRepository();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Person>> getPlayers() {
        return mApiResponse;
    }

    public void performSearch(String name){
        mApiResponse.addSource(mApiRepo.search(name), new Observer<List<Person>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Person> apiResponse)            {
                mApiResponse.setValue(apiResponse);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity

```
bt_search.setOnClickListener {
    val player_name = et_player.text.toString()
    viewModel.performSearch(player_name)
}
```

## Project scope

I'm in a personal project

## Goals

Use MVVM + Live data + Repository pattern

## Problem

I've only found tutorials with a simple approach: observe a `LiveData` object that access to a `repository` object and fetch data only once.

In example: Fetch all people (`select * from people`) from web service.

My case: Fetch people that mach a name (`select * from people where name=?`) from web service.

https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890
https://medium.com/@sriramr083/error-handling-in-retrofit2-in-mvvm-repository-pattern-a9c13c8f3995

## Doubts

Is a good idea use `MediatorLiveData` class to `merge` all requests took from user input?

Should I use `MutableLiveData` and change the `repository` class and use a custom clousure?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Does it work for whatever you want it to do? Please add a description of what problem your code solves in less general terms. You're doing something with people and companions, but if you tell us *why* you're doing what you're doing and *what* it is (example usage would be great) the extra context would be quite helpful for reviewers.

Comment: @Mast I've updated the question. If you need more details just let me know.